# c# Which is the better way to give random number to function

Tags: c#, random

Which is better and is there a difference in the random results ?

```
 void Func1(Random rand)
{
var num=rand.Next();
}

 void Func2(ref Random rand)
{
var num=rand.Next();
}
```

Comment: If I can remember correctly, `Random` is a class so you will be passing by reference anyway, there's no need for `ref`. Somebody can correct me if I am wrong however.

Comment: The only time `ref` makes a difference is when you assign something to the passed in parameter.

Comment: @JamesS There's a difference between passing by reference and reference types.  Passing by reference means you can assign a new value to the parameter and the change will effect the variable passed to the method (this applies to both value and reference types).  A reference type just means that updating internal values of the object will be seen outside the method since it's basically a pointer to memory where as a mutable value type (which are evil) would just update the value in the current stack.

Comment: Why would you provide `Random` as `ref`? That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent. You don't update the `rand` reference in the function so passing it by `ref` does nothing.

Rule of thumb: don't use `ref` unless you *absolutely* have to and understand what it does.

Answer (score 2):

1) Never use `ref` if you don't need it explicitely.

2) Usually you shouldn't need to pass `Random` through `method`s. If  you have to, probably you are doing something wrong in your code.

Why? Because to be sure of a true randomness, it's better to always use the same `Random` instance instead of creating many of them.

That's why you should always declare one and use it around, like in this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RandomNumbersPrinter randomNumbersPrinter = new RandomNumbersPrinter();
        int randomInteger = randomNumbersPrinter.GetRandomInteger();
        Console.WriteLine(randomInteger);
    }
}

public class RandomNumbersPrinter
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public int GetRandomInteger()
    {
        return _random.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically that's going to use a new `Random` for each instance of `RandomNumbersPrinter`.  Making it `static` would be better.

Comment: True, it depends on the needs. Atleast avoiding to use always a different one for every method of the same class is a good starting point

Comment: The most important thing is to avoid creating new `Random` objects in a tight loop, which will lead to duplicate numbers because of how it seeds.  The best way to avoid that is to make sure `Random` is static and is only created once.

Comment: FYI, you could set it in a `static` constructor to avoid the null check.  And making it `readonly` so it cannot be reset.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Random` is a reference type, the only difference is that the *reference* to the instance get copied when calling `Func1`.

In `Func2`, you are passing the actual existing reference to the `Random` itself to the method.

Please consult the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference) for more information about this.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't use the `ref` keyword here unless you intend to assign `rand` to a new `Random` object in the method.